# How to give several buttons different styling to make them "behave" as individual

Tags: html, css, button

```css
body {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/LMYkPk3.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}

button {
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: cursive;
    line-height: 1.8;
    appearance: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

section.flat button {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-shadow: -1px 1px #417cb8;
  border: none;
}

section.flat button:hover,
section.flat button.hover {
  background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid orange;
}

section.flat button:active,
section.flat button.active {
  background-color: mintcream;
  text-shadow: -1px 1px #193047;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
            <title></title>
               </head>
             <body>
            <div id="line"></div>
            
<section class="flat">
    <button>button</button>
    <button>another</button> <!-- works fine if just one button ... but as soon as there more they all "selects" when hovered over one (change of depth ...) -->
    
</section>
   
     
            
            
            
            
            </body>
            
</html>
```

My question: I have two buttons on my page and they both seem to behave the same. But when I hover over just one of them, both of them change their behavior(depth). How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add different id to different buttons to make them individually distinguishable. Then do the separate styling using those two IDs. I have modified your code and here goes the working code--

```
<body>
        <div id="line"></div>

<section class="flat">
<button id = "btn1">button</button>
<button id="btn2">another</button> 

  </section>
</body>
<!--the css-->
button {
display:inline-block;
margin: 0 10px 0 0;
padding: 5px 20px;
font-size: 15px;
font-family: cursive;
line-height: 1.8;
appearance: none;
box-shadow: none;
border-radius: 20px;
    }

   button:focus 
  {
outline: none;
   }
   #btn1 {
       background-color: #f0f0f8;
     }



    section.flat button:hover,
      section.flat button.hover {
     background-color: transparent;
      border: 2px solid orange;
        }

   #btn1:active,
    section.flat button.active {
     background-color: mintcream;
    text-shadow: -1px 1px #193047;
    color: black;
        }
```

I have modified your `CSS` a bit just to show how it works.
As you can see in the below fiddle both the button has different `backgroung-color`. Cheers!

[Working JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3hmqjdvL/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `<button id="btn-1"></button>`, `<button id="btn-2"></button>`, etc. so you have an id for for each button. This is expected behavior because there is no unique identifier for each button. Your css is telling it to press down every button, not a specific one.

Comment: i tried id them but then they both went gray. could you please be more specific ... i think still smth on css missing ...

Comment: did you apply to the css also? `#btn-1`, `#btn-1:hover`, etc. If you can't figure it out I'll send you a jsfiddle

Comment: i made individual button settings in css now as well as sections in html. seems to work now as individual btn but they're not in one line anymore. i tried to put them under one div class and put display: inline; (did not work) @lazyboy78